# Arduino ISP ATtiny problems

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny, bootloader, isp

As I was trying to program my ATtiny chip with my arduino, I ran across some problems. Note that I know that this problem is faced almost in every Q and A site and forum so don't flag me as repeat *yet*. (I was trying to burn the bootloader so my chip runs at 8MHz)

So this is the error code:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -pattiny85 -cstk500v1 -PCOM1 -b19200 -e -Uefuse:w:0xff:m -Uhfuse:w:0xdf:m -Ulfuse:w:0xe2:m 

 avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

 System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM1
     Using Programmer              : stk500v1
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Error while burning bootloader.
```

* **deleted attempt 2 to 9** *

Although a solution to this problem will be very nice, that is not my intention here. I tried almost all solutions I have found and non of them work, and I want to know why. So these are my questions:

1. What does this code actually mean? The for example the "programmer", is it referring to the Arduino or the ATtiny(or the highly unlikely, laptop that im using.)
2. How do I access more error codes, if there are any, as I think that these codes really do not tell that much.
3. [Solved]To prevent Arduino from auto-resetting, almost all tutorials connect the Reset pin to the Ground pin with a 10uF capacitor, and I don't have one. I tried with various other capacitors that I have(22uF, 0.4uF, 0.22uF, 47uF, and 330uF). I do not know how does the capacitance affect the anti auto-resetting function, so some explanation here is helpful.
   [solved]

**EDIT: I disconnected the ATtiny and the same error code persists. This, I conclude as either I never had a proper connection with the ATtiny, or the problem is with the communication of my laptop with the Arduino.**

Comment: You need to select the correct programmer in them menu. You need to select Aruino as ISP. Also try the "upload using programmer" option.

Comment: @Gerben I am on Arduino as ISP. I just tried the upload using programmer, but same error code.

Comment: Re 10μF capacitor, a 22μF should work in its place.    See [*ArduinoISP on Uno requires 10uF cap -- WHY?*](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=104435.0) on arduino.cc for more.

Comment: @JamesWaldby-jwpat7 I have been looking for something like this for ages. Thanks James. Now that's one problem out of the way.

Answer (score 2):

I did not download Arduino as ISP into my arduino. I realize how much of an idiot I am. The capacitor wasn't even needed for some reasons. I might make an intensive tutorial on this project.

Comment: I love asian tech culture. NO SHAME IN MAKING A MISTAKE! If LadyAda were asian, the PIs would have pinout text on the boards. +1